# Symmetric extension to Poisson Mass Function - Conditional Variance

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, variance, poisson-distribution

Let $I=\pm1$ with equal chance. Let $Y$ be independent of I and have distribution $\textrm{Po}(\lambda)$. Consider $\displaystyle X\stackrel{d}{=}IY$. Use the conditional variance formula to compute $\textrm{Var} X$.

My attempt:
$\textrm{Var} X=\mathbb{E}(\textrm{Var}(X|I))+\textrm{Var}(\mathbb{E}(X|I))$

For $X|I$, given $I=-1$, $X$ is equal in distribution to $-Y$. Given $I=1$, $X$ is equal in distribution to $Y$. So $X|I = \mathrm{sgn}(I)Y = IY$. But I'm stuck here, because it gets me back to where I started. Can someone help me? Is what I've done right so far?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use the definition of variance here? Maybe I'm missing something but shouldn't it just be $\text{Var}(X) = E[(IY - E(IY))^2] = E[I^2 Y^2] = \lambda^2 + \lambda$?

Comment: Hi Gregory, thanks for your comment. That's the given solution for this question. But I would like to do it using the conditional variance formula if possible. I get E(X|I)=0 so Var X = E(Var(X|I)), but I am not sure how to get the answer.

Comment: @Balkys While $E[IX]=E[I] E[X] = 0$, it is not true that $E[X \mid I]=0$, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you condition on $I$ then you can treat $I$ as a constant when computing the conditional expectation/variance. So
$$E[X \mid I] = E[IY \mid I] = I E[Y \mid I] = IE[Y] = \lambda I,$$
and then you can compute $\text{Var}(\lambda I)$.
Similarly,
$$\text{Var}(X \mid I) = \text{Var}(IY \mid I) = I^2 \text{Var}(Y \mid I) = \text{Var}(Y) = \lambda.$$

Comment: Thank you! I understand now.

Comment: @Balkys Note that the equalities $E[Y \mid I] = E[Y]$ and $\text{Var}(Y \mid I) = \text{Var}(Y)$ rely on the fact that $Y$ and $I$ are independent.